# javacc Absolute offset for specialToken

Tags: java, parsing, token, syntax-highlighting, javacc

I need to add absolute information to each token to integrate an in-house syntax highlight framework.

I have followed this post:
http://ramkulkarni.com/blog/capturing-absolute-offsets-for-javaccjjtree-tokens/

And it works ok for regular tokens.

Comments are captured as special tokens and for some reason
`CommonTokenAction` is not applied to those. I hace debugged the issue and the generated `XXTokenManager` is missing a call to `CommonTokenAction` after a

```
    if ((jjtoSpecial[jjmatchedKind >> 6] & (1L << (jjmatchedKind & 077))) != 0L) {
                                matchedToken = jjFillToken(); 
...
```

Is there any additional flag I can set for this to work?
Otherwise I can manually change the file but I don't like it since it is auto-generated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In JavaCC there are three kinds of tokens. Skipped tokens are not visible to the parser and no `Token` object will be made for it. Regular tokens are visible to the parser. Special tokens are not visible to the parser, but `Token` objects are made for them.  Common token actions are only applied to regular tokens.

First Solution: Usually if you are doing syntax highlighting there is no need for a parser and so no reason for any tokens to be special tokens.  Just make comments and such like regular tokens so that the common token action is applied to them.

Second solution: Make all tokens either regular or special.  Then the following should work.

```
public void CommonTokenAction(Token t)
{
    int c = getCurrentTokenAbsolutePosition() + t.image.length();
    do {
        t.absoluteEndColumn = c ;
        c -= t.image.length() ;
        t.absoluteBeginColumn = c;
        t = t.specialToken ;
    } while( t != null ) ;
}
```